# Stemming/descended from = espresso da?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Here is an article I just read: https://www.ilpost.it/2023/05/31/djokovic-kosovo-serbia/

Given all the definitions of the words esprimere, esprimersi, and espresso in pons.com and collinsdictionary.com, I don't see how "il controverso presidente della Bosnia-Erzegovina" can be "espresso dall’etnia serba". Obviously, the guy *comes* from that ethnicity, from that community, but is **espresso** the best way to express that? Maybe they should have said "proveniente da" or "che viene da" instead.

Comment: The choice of <esprimere> recalls the idea of election, where votes are "espressi" by electors.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase is correct and usual.

*"il controverso presidente della Bosnia-Erzegovina espresso dall’etnia serba*", actually, doesn't mean that *"he comes from this ethnicity"*.

Instead, **it means that this president has been, in a sense, 'produced',** probably through elections, **by this ethnicity** and represents it, regardless his ethnical origin.

It means '*è manifestazione di*.., *proviene da..*, è *prodotto da*
(but not necessarily through elections).

It is one of the meanings of the verb *esprimere*: *to produce*, *to generate*:

**Treccani** (lett.) spremere, trarre fuori, generare, far nascere

**Hoepli** 3. (lett.) spremere fuori, estrarre: esprimendo dai fiori la stilla essenziale (d'annunzio)
|| Generare, produrre

**Garzanti** 3. (lett.) produrre, emanare, creare.

See https://dict.numerosamente.it/definizione/esprimere

A synonymous could be *essere espressione di* or
*essere emanazione di*: *provenire da*, *essere prodotto da*, *derivare da*: for example *un provvedimento emanazione di un gruppo*.

A sua volta da *emanare*:

https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=emanare+treccani

The dictionaries  quoted above say that, in this sense, it is a literary term, but in some expressions, as in your case, this is not literary, but is usual.
For instance, it is usual when used in a political context, for example *un governo espresso dalla minoranza*. See:

https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/governo-minoritario